# Mi Formulario verifica el envio, pero no recibo ningún correo

Tags: php, formularios, servidor, phpmailer

Mi formulario se envía mediante PHPmailer, y regresa la respuesta de mensaje enviado, ademas se verifica con un recaptcha de Google, parece que todo funciona perfectamente, el detalle esta en que no recibo en ningún momento el mail de el formulario.

No se si este usando mal el PHPmailer o el problema sea la verificación de el recaptcha, pero ya intente de muchas otras maneras y esta es la única forma en la que la respuesta es positiva pero el correo no llega.
El archivo "config.php" solo es para tener ahí a donde van a mandarse los formularios y donde están las claves de Recaptcha.

Originalmente intente hacer los envios mediante el el servidor de google desde una cuenta de Gmail, pero sin importar como colocara la info jamas consegui el mensaje de exito

```
<?php

require "config/config.php"; //include config file
// GOOGLE GOODNESS
  ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
      $secretKey = "$yoursecretkey;";
      $request = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretKey}&response={$recaptchaResponse}&remoteip={$userIP}");
      if(!strstr($request, "true")){
          echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<strong>Error!</strong>
Hubo un error con el Captcha, te falto seleccionar la cassilla de verificaciÃ³n o eres un robot :)</div>';
      }
      else{
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $message=
        'Nombre: '.$_POST['nombre'].'<br />
        Correo:    '.$_POST['correo'].'<br />
        Telefono:  '.$_POST['telefono'].'<br />
        Fecha de Salida:  '.$_POST['inicio'].'<br />
        Fecha de Regreso:   '.$_POST['regreso'].'<br/>
        Recorrido a Realizar:  '.$_POST['recorrido'].'<br />
        Unidad Requerida:  '.$_POST['unidad'].'<br />
        Detalles: '.$_POST['detalles'].'
        ';

        require "PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class


                    // Instantiate Class
                    $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
            $mail->Host = "smtp.marcopolo.org.mx"; 


                    // Authentication
                    $mail->Username   = $senderEmail; 
                    $mail->Password   = $senderPassword;

                    // Compose
                    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['correo'], $_POST['nombre']);
                    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['correo'], $_POST['nombre']);
                    $mail->Subject = "Correo de MarcoPolo";     
                    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

                    // Send To
                    $mail->AddAddress($receiverEmail, $receiverName); // Where to send it - Recipient
                    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!
                    $message = $result ? '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong>Mensaje Enviado</div>' : '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong>
Hubo un error con el Captcha, te falto seleccionar la cassilla de verificaciÃ³n o eres un robot :)</div>'; 
                    unset($mail);
                }
              }
          }


 ?>
```

Comment: el servidor de gmail siempre ocasiona problemas al recibir correos que sean enviados desde alguna web que estes desarrollando.

Comment: @JorgeHernandez lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general. Saludos.

Comment: @JorgeHernandez lo se por eso opte por no usar el servidor de Gmail y usar el el de mi propio dominio, ahi es donde no puedo hacer el envio de información.